# Scala compiler can't find the unmarshalling implicits in route declaration

Tags: scala, implicit, akka-http

I'm trying to build a REST server using this tutorial:

https://spindance.com/reactive-rest-services-akka-http/

However, having reached the "Responding with JSON" section, I've noticed that my code doesn't compile, and I can't make POST requests. This is the error that I'm getting:

```
Error:(59, 18) could not find implicit value for parameter um: akka.http.scaladsl.unmarshalling.FromRequestUnmarshaller[Health]
        entity(as[Health]) { statusReport =>
                 ^
```

Having looked at other tutorials, I've found out that you need to include an object containing an implicit variable for the class that I'm trying to unmarshall. I did that, and I even imported the httpx library, but I'm still getting this error. My code is given below.

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.StatusCodes
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives._
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Route
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import akka.pattern.ask
import akka.util.Timeout

import spray.json._
import DefaultJsonProtocol._
import spray.httpx.SprayJsonSupport.sprayJsonUnmarshaller

import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.io.StdIn

object JsonImplicits extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val healthFormat = jsonFormat2(Health)
}

object MyApplication {
  val host = "localhost"
  val port = 8080

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    implicit val system = ActorSystem("simple-rest-system")

    // Something to do with flows
    implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

    // A reference to a specific thread pool
    // You can configure thread pool options through it
    // It is the engine that executes the actors
    implicit val executionContext = system.dispatcher

    val requestHandler = system.actorOf(RequestHandler.props(), "requestHandler")

    //Define the route
    val route : Route = {
      implicit val timeout = Timeout(20 seconds)
      import JsonImplicits._
      import spray.httpx.SprayJsonSupport._

      path("health") {
        get {
          onSuccess(requestHandler ? GetHealthRequest) {
            case response: HealthResponse =>
              complete(StatusCodes.OK, s"Everything is ${response.health.status}!")
            case _ =>
              complete(StatusCodes.InternalServerError)
          }
        }
      } ~ post {
        // Entity extracts the body of the POST request and then converts it into a
        // Health object

        entity(as[Health]) { statusReport =>
          onSuccess(requestHandler ? SetStatusRequest(statusReport)) {
            case response: HealthResponse =>
              complete(StatusCodes.OK,s"Posted health as ${response.health.status}!")
            case _ =>
              complete(StatusCodes.InternalServerError)
          }
        }
      }
    }

    //Start up and listen for requests
    val bindingFuture = Http().bindAndHandle(route, host, port)
    println(s"Waiting for requests at http://$host:$port/...\nHit RETURN to terminate")
    StdIn.readLine()

    //Shutdown
    bindingFuture.flatMap(_.unbind())
    system.terminate()
  }
}
```

Comment: PS: If the tutorial is outdated, what is the most modern way of building a REST server using akka-http?

Comment: Does it have something to do with the scope of that implicit variable? I can't quite get my head around it.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/hseeberger/akka-http-json for some json libs for scala adapted to akka-http marshallers